# How can get balance for btc/bch address and block?

Tags: api, block, balance

How can get balance for btc/bch address and block ?

Similar to web3.eth.getBalance for Ethereum

Comment: Bitcoin doesn't have a similar functionality as `web3`.

Answer (score 2):

A BTC/BCH node does not supply aggregate information on addresses.
You could consult one of the block explorers out there, most of them do provide balances for addresses.